# Date Range Query in Sqlite for my phone gap mobile app

Tags: sqlite, cordova

I am trying to get some data from sqlite db of my phone gap app by providing From Date and To Date. What surprise me is that when i am trying this -

```
SELECT * FROM PATHISTORY WHERE PATDATE >= '2014-04-20' AND PATDATE <= '2014-04-20' ORDER BY PATDATE DESC; 

--->> I do not get any result. result.length = 0. I have also tried the query by using BETWEEN but still no result came.
But when i do this - 
SELECT * FROM PATHISTORY WHERE PATDATE >= '2014-04-20';

--> I get proper data.
```

What am i doing wrong here?? Please help !! Below is by table structure, just in case u need to look at it -

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PATHISTORY( \
            PATHISTORYID VARCHAR NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY , \
            PATDATE DATETIME \
            );
```

Comment: How do you define proper data? do you have any records with that date?

Comment: Yes. that is how i am getting PROPER DATA when i run last 2 queries !!!

Comment: i have edited my question. can you please now help me !!

Comment: The 2 statements you are giving aren't equivalant if there aren't any records with

PATDATE=='2014-04-20'  So my Question is do you have any rows in yout table with PATDATE=='2014-04-20'???

1st query returns 0 rows.

However 2nd query wil return the rows that

 PATDATE>='2014-04-20'

Comment: Yes i do have records.

Comment: ALso in your table I only see a LOCATIONDATE field not a PATHDATE field

Comment: edited that also sir.. sorry for that.

Comment: Do u think is their any problem in AND operator or may be in <= operator? sorry for this stupid thought but that is only what i can think as of now !

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that `PATDATE` is a `DATETIME` field reather than `DATE`, that means that you are storing a time value also in your Database, thus the first query is equvalent to:

```
SELECT * FROM PATHISTORY WHERE PATDATE == '2014-04-20 00:00:00'
```

and the second:

```
SELECT * FROM PATHISTORY WHERE PATDATE >= '2014-04-20 00:00:00'
```

I suspect that if you run If you run:

```
 SELECT * FROM PATHISTORY WHERE PATDATE == '2014-04-20'
```

you won't get any results, because you don't have any record at time `00:00:00`

Comment: For me, last 2 statements are giving same result. The problem is coming only if i give 2 dates or if I say when i use AND operator or may be <= operator !!

Comment: OH !! can i even write a query like this...SELECT * FROM PATHISTORY WHERE PATDATE >= '2014-04-20';
AND,
SELECT * FROM PATHISTORY WHERE PATDATE = '2014-04-20';..... i think i need to edit my question.. :)

Comment: So.. what shall i do now ? Actually i can not change the data type. Can you suggest me something please !!

Comment: Anybody plz help me on this !!